# React-Native-Share-Menu | Error: couldn't find provider on M1 Macbooks

Tags: ios, react-native, share, share-extension

- I'm writing a share extension for ReactNative built app.
- I'm using [ReactNativeShareMenu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share-menu) package.

Whenever I build this app on a M1 architecture MacBook, I get the following error:

```swift
Error: couldn't find provider
```

But on intel MacBooks, it works fine.

The code at `index.share.js` is as follows:

```js
const Share = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    ShareMenuReactView.data().then(({mimeType, data}) => {
        ShareMenuReactView.continueInApp({data, mimeType});
    });
  }, []);

  return <View />;

};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ShareMenuModuleComponent', () => Share);
```

PS: Rosetta is installed just fine and I tried using RosettaTerminal to run the app too. Nothing changed.